# Can I index on collection of String in hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, indexing, collections, hql

I want to search on a collection of string in an entity but my query was so slowly so i decide to create index on this collection.
Can I index on collection of String in hibernate ? and how can i do it . I use @OrderColumn but it makes error.

```
@Entity
Class A {
     @ElementCollection
     private List<String> something;
     }
```

Comment: sorry i edit the question

Comment: post more of your code and try to explain it a bit better what you want to do/achieve